# My Kivy interface with socket is just a blank popup and reported no wrong

Tags: python, sockets, kivy

I want to make a kivy interface that can display socket communication (The information sent by the server can be displayed on the Label of the kivy interface), but it is always wrong: The program reported no error, and it just popped up a blank form.

Moreover, I have posted a similar question, the following is my revised code after the simplification of the whole program.
I would be very grateful if you could answer my questions。

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from client import Mysocket


class AnchorLayoutWidget(AnchorLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_data = Mysocket()
        self.show_data()

    def show_data(self):
        self.ids.recv.text = str(self.get_data.recv)


class AnchorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AnchorLayoutWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AnchorApp().run()
```

### server.py

```
import socket

sk = socket.socket()

sk.bind(('127.0.0.1', 1029))

sk.listen()
conn, addr = sk.accept()

while True:
    info = input('<<')
    conn.send(bytes(info, encoding='utf-8'))
```

### client.py

```
import socket

class Mysocket:

    def __init__(self):
        sk = socket.socket()
        sk.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1029))

        if True:
            print('connect successfully!')

        while True:
            self.ret = sk.recv(1024)
            self.recv = self.ret.decode('utf-8')
```

### anchor.kv

```
<AnchorLayoutWidget>:
    padding: 20
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        Button:
            text: "hello"
            background_color: 0,1,1,1
            size_hint: .5,.5
            font_size: 40

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        Button:
            text: "world"
            background_color: 0,1,1,1
            size_hint: .5,.5
            font_size: 40

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Label:
            id: recv
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'middle'
            italic: True
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            text: "123"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.5
            font_size: 30
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Label:
            id:ID_input
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba:(.1,.1,.1,.1)
            text:"123"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.5
            font_size: 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your show_data() method in a loop:

```
class AnchorLayoutWidget(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_data = Mysocket()

def show_data(self):
    self.ids.recv.text = str(self.get_data.recv)
```

Edit:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
# from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
# from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.clock import Clock


class Mysocket():
    def __init__(self):
        self.recv = None


class AnchorLayoutWidget(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_data = Mysocket()
        self.get_data.recv = "Hello world"
        # self.show_data()

    def show_data(self, dt):
        self.ids.recv_data.text = str(self.get_data.recv)

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.show_data, 0.1)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AnchorLayoutWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()

def on_start(self):
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.show_data, 0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however there are still some troubles with my code: The kivy interface is still a blank window，The following is my code after modification：
``` from kivy.clock import Clock
class AnchorLayoutWidget(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):`
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_data = Mysocket()
        # self.show_data()

    def show_data(self):
        self.ids.recv.text = str(self.get_data.recv)

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.show_data, 0.1) ```

Comment: `from kivy.clock import Clock

class AnchorLayoutWidget(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_data = Mysocket()
        # self.show_data()

    def show_data(self):
        self.ids.recv.text = str(self.get_data.recv)

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.show_data, 0.1)`

Comment: Thanks for your help very much  I tried to run your edit code, but I only get a black blank window here, and I have modified `self.ids.recv_data.text = str(self.get_data.recv)` to my label's id `self.ids.recv.text` like my kivy file. Then Mysocket in your code is just a init def, I think it can run without the sever.py? Moreover, what is the dt in `def show_data`? Thanks for your anwer again.